# Choosing right storage for configuration

Tags: database, configuration, nosql, storage

We've applications and services which use a lot of configuration most of which is currently hard-coded in the java code and spread over a lot of classes. Obviously, this needs to change and we want this to be centralized at one place and that should be retrieved and exposed by one of the services (say ConfigurationService) which also incorporates caching the configuration for its clients for better performance. We also need to have dynamic reloading of the configuration for long-running applications and avoid restarts. I would like to get some comments on the kind of storage I should be using for this purpose -

### Kind of Data -

The data need not be structured. It could be a simple key-value pair or it could be multi-key, single value pair. Here are some random examples of configuration -

- "Client_Id" -> "ABC" (Simple key-value)
- ["User_Type": "Admin", "Region": "Mumbai", "User_rating": "9"] -> ["Commission": "10%"] (Multi-key value)
- ["User_Id" -> "123"] -> ["WhitelistedRegions"->"Mumbai, Goa"]  (Context based configuration, value is a list)

### Storage Solutions -

Basically, the set and type of parameters which form a key are not fixed which gives me a hint that this configuration is not really structured. The volume of entire configuration won't really be huge. There will be very few writes as compared to the reads.

- **Database (RDBMS / NoSQL)** - The advantage of using a database table could be security and backups it provides. Since this doesn't look like relational data, I would consider a NoSQL solution. I've not really used any of them personally, please tell me which one suits this kind of data better. As there could be a lot of different keys, we should be able to pick exact keys (some kind of indexing). Database usage will introduce latency, but efficient caching can be built to overcome this (as there won't be too many writes to the configuration). The data is easier to query.
- **Files (XML or other flat files)** - We can keep it simple using the files. Caching can be used in case of files as well. As long as the entire configuration can be imported in memory (RAM), that's an option as well (selective cache invalidation has to be implemented). Files provide versioning, permissions/security has to be looked into. XML files especially can become messier if they grow large. The data may not be easy to query if we're using files.

Which should be a better storage solution assuming that dynamic reloading and cache invalidation are implemented separately? What other factors should be considered here?

If files are to be used to store such configuration, what are the better file formats for such use-cases?

Note: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815271/designing-configuration-storage-retrieval-system) on SO, but probably didn't frame the question as clearly as I should have, so created a new one instead of making heavy edits.

Comment: Some questions: 1) Are your "applications and services" so cohesive that it makes sense having a single configuration service? 2) Are there no external constraints on your design choice? 3) Who is going to modify the configuration and how?

Comment: 1) We use GWT apps with gwt RPCs which talk to spring-based backend services (remoting), so usually all the backend service APIs are utilized by RPCs, we can do similar thing here, having a configuration service in the backend and exposing its APIs to RPCs.  2) Apart from what I mentioned above, not really. Also we're flexible to consider using different data stores like NoSQL (presently I personally think that it would be an overkill) as well. 3) As of now, developers and internal users modify the configuration, but having a front-end app to do it is a feasible option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, please do yourself a favor and evaluate whether or not [Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius) or [Curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator) are appropriate for your needs.  Archaius is probably more appropriate for application and container configuration where Curator is probably better for machine level configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you provide suggest you might want some sort of rules engine. To show what I mean, I interpret your examples as having the following semantics:

```
if (true) {
    Client_Id = "ABC";
}
if (User_Type == "Admin" && Region == "Mumbai" && "User_rating" == "9") {
    Commission = "10%";
}
if (User_Id == "123") {
    WhitelistedRegions" = ["Mumbai", "Goa"];
}
```

If my interpretation is wrong, then perhaps you could edit your question to clarify your intended meaning. On the other hand, if my interpretation is correct, then I am not aware of any particular configuration syntax that is tailor-made for your requirements. Instead, I suspect you will have to shoehorn the semantics of what you want into the constraints of whatever configuration syntax you decide to use.

The way I might try to shoehorn (my interpretation of) your examples into the syntax of [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) (disclaimer: I am its main developer) is as follows:

```
uid-rule {
    # unconditional
    client_Id = "ABC";
}
uid-rule {
    condition {
        User_Type = "Admin";
        Region = "Mumbai";
        User_rating = "9";
    }
    Commission = "10%%";
}
uid-rule {
    condition { User_Id = "123"; }
    WhitelistedRegions = ["Mumbai", "Goa"];
}
```

I recommend you read Chapter 2 of the *Config4* Getting Started* manual ([HTML](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-config4star-syntax.html), [PDF](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-getting-started-guide.pdf)) so you can understand the syntax used in the above example.

My initial attempt at shoehorning your examples into XML syntax is:

```
<rules>
    <rule>
        <property name="client_Id" value="ABC"/>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <condition name="User_Type" value="Admin"/>
        <condition name="Region" value="Mumbai"/>
        <condition name="User_rating" value="9"/>
        <property name="Commission" value="10%"/>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <condition name="User_Id" value="123"/>
        <property name="WhitelistedRegions" value="Mumbai, Goa"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Note that neither a Config4* parser nor an XML parser will give you the semantics you want out-of-the-box. Instead, you should write a class called, say, `RulesEngine`. Such a class would: (1) parse a configuration file to obtain the rules and cache the parsed representation in memory; (2) provide a simple API for querying that in-memory set of rules; and (3) provide a `reloadConfiguration()` method that re-parses the configuration file. Your application would somehow trigger the invocation of the `reloadConfiguration()` method (for example, once every few minutes).

If you use XML for your configuration syntax, then I suggest that your achieve your centralization goal by storing the XML file on a web server. The XML parser can retrieve the file form there. If you use Config4* syntax, then the Config4* integration with `curl` makes it possible to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to look at the situation.

1. The way I decide about where to store the data is generally based on type of data.

   If I am reading your data correctly it specifies client id, commission based on user location and rating and regions applicable to particular user. To me it is more of a business static data than configuration (though this is not going to change frequently). Therefore I would prefer to keep it in database.
2. Do I need to provide a screen for users to update this data. If there is a UI you don't have to go through raising a ticket or release process to do this in PROD env. But having a UI will move the choice to database.
3. If there is no UI then probably file configuration is a better choice. Because you can have a file watcher service in your application to watch this configuration file. Once the file is modified this service will read the file and update the configuration without restart. Dynamic reload in case of database may not be as simple. You can still provide an administrative screen to manually trigger the configuration reload.
4. For type of file you can go with choice proposed by Ciaran but that would require some additional learning. Considering you don't have big volume of configuration you can stick to xml.
5. Caching the data I don't think will have any impact on choice between database and file as it is easily possible for both. However if you are using some ORM like hibernate you will be saved from the additional effort of caching your data but ORM brings another complexity of defining Class mapping to database tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The example is just one of the configuration pieces we have/need, all of that isn't really business static data.

Comment: Then you may want to split your data in two categories and have separate implementation for each. You can then provide a common layer to access the data so that it is transparent for callers.

Comment: Typical business data access is not a problem, this question is about the detailed design for the other use-case (as the question describes).